# How can I make different backgrounds for multiple selectors in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with five sections in it. I'd like to have different background colors for each one.

Usually, one would create a class for each:

CSS

```
.b1 {background-color: blue;}
.b2 {background-color: red;}
.b3 {background-color: black;}
.b4 {background-color: beige;}
.b5 {background-color: blue;}
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <section class="b1">Block 1</section>
   <section class="b2">Block 2</section>
   <section class="b3">Block 3</section>
   <section class="b4">Block 4</section>
   <section class="b5">Block 5</section>
</div>
```

But I recently saw someone else's HTML that had different colors for each one, yet there were no classes in any of the section tags. Is there some other way of doing this in CSS?

Tried to create different background colors for each section without classes in each HTML tag.

Comment: you can use nthchild css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
lot easier that way but its good practice to use classes

Comment: Best way is to use classes, try to always use standar methods for standar tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript, you access to the child elements and add the color, there is an example:

```
let container = document.getElementById('itemsContainer');
let childItems = Array.from(container.children);
childItems.forEach(function (element, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
    if (index == 1) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    /*
    if .... n times
    */
});
```

To makeit more clean, you can save the colors value in an array and do this:

```
let container = document.getElementById('itemsContainer');
let childItems = Array.from(container.children);
let colorsValue = ['blue', 'red', 'black', 'beige', 'blue'];
childItems.forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = colorsValue[index];
});
```

Comment: @DavidMiddleton are you really accepting (and using) a JS solution for something that you can easily do with CSS?

Comment: Use document.querySelectorAll to simplify the code.

Comment: Honestly, an array of colours accessed using the index of the `forEach()` loop would be easier than using so many independent `if` statements... Also, if you were looking for a JavaScript answer (which is entirely unnecessary for the problem you're presenting), you should add that tag to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you want to avoid classes. That being said, if your sections have same parent you can use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo class:

```css
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: darksalmon;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: papayawhip;
}

section:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>Block 1</section>
  <section>Block 2</section>
  <div>this is not a section</div>
  <section>Block 3</section>
  <section>Block 4</section>
  <section>Block 5</section>
</div>
```